# awaitMessages starting without reply

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a Channel Lock command, which uses awaitMessages to confirm it. However, if you do not confirm it, it says confirm and does it anyway. This is my code:

```js
 if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(`MANAGE_CHANNELS`)) return message.reply('I lack the required permissions to run this command. (Required Permissions: ``MANAGE_CHANNELS``)');          
        if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")){
            const channel = message.channel;
            
            const Discord = require("discord.js");
            let role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === args.join(" "));
            if(!role){
                message.reply("please mention a role.")
            } else{
                let replyMessage = message.reply('Are you sure you want to continue this command, it will remove send permissions from the role you mentioned. Type ``yes`` to continue.')
            let filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id && msg.content.toLowerCase() == 'yes';
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 20000}).then(collected => {
            
                message.reply('Confirmed!');

                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Channel Locked")
                .setColor("RED")
                .setDescription(`Channel locked to the specified role`)

                message.channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false
                })
                .then(channel => channel.send(embed))
                .catch(console.error);
            });
            }
            

        }  else{
            message.reply("You lack the required permissions to do this (Required Permissions: 'MANAGE_CHANNELS')")
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `awaitMessages()` function returns a collection of messages collected after following a respected filter. From that sense, we cannot use `msg.content`, as you cannot read the content of a collection, but would have to check for a certain value inside of it. Here comes `.first()`, that returns the first value inside of the collection.

#### Final Code

```
let filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 20000}).then(collected => {           
        if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() !== 'yes') return;
        message.reply('Confirmed!');

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Channel Locked")
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription(`Channel locked to the specified role`)

        message.channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: false
        })
        .then(channel => channel.send(embed))
        .catch(console.error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I was wondering how I would make that send a message saying timeout if they didn't say yes within the timeframe as if you don't answer it sends this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

Comment: `awaitMessages` provides an `errors` option where you can create an alert if anything went bad. I'd suggest reading more about it. From there, you can wrap the function with `try` and `catch` functions, that would alert in the case that time has ran out.